# how to convert dictionary to json format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

There are many question asked in regard to this topic but i haven't been able to find the answer.

I am working on a react native app and I need to covert this dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *title = @{ @"title": @"a journey to heaven",
                       @"title": @"history of gun Powder",
                       @"title": @"intro to Java"} ;
```

I want to be able to convert this into JSON so that I can reference the elements in table view as array.title

Please help, Thanks!

Comment: Check NSJSONSerialization  class :)

Comment: i did, but these have same keys

Comment: @L887: Did you check the dictionary after creating it ? How many key value pair is there ?

Comment: Your dictionary isn't valid. Keys must be unique. Your `title` dictionary will end up with one key/value pair in it. That must be solved long before you deal with JSON.

Comment: Perhaps you want an array of dictionaries. Then each dictionary can have its "title" key.

Answer (score 0):

Its not entirely clear why you want to convert to JSON.  But I think I understand that you want to be able to reference your collection in a tableview, right?  If thats all you need to do, you dont need JSON, you just need an array.  You could just do this - first declare a class property (means the entire class can access it, declared in the header file)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *titles;
```

Then declare the array in an initial array like viewDidLoad :

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
   self.titles = @[@"a journey to heaven", @"history of gun Powder", @"intro to Java"];
}
```

In the numberOfRowsInSection method, return the size of the array, eg :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return self.titles.count;
}
```

Then finally in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, access your array to populate the cell in the tableview :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
   cell.textLabel.text = [self.titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   return cell;
}
```

Thats not everything you need for a tableview but its the most important bits. Have a look at a tableview tutorial, of which there are thousands on the net.

In my experience, you only need to think about converting to JSON (string for eg) when either saving a file to disc or posting it to a web service.  You didnt mention doing that though, so Im hoping this is what you need.